# How do I dynamically create class and persist it to the Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence

How do I create persist-able class dynamically and persist it to the Google App Engine datastore

Comment: do you mean to convert a regular class into a persistable one at runtime, and then persist it to the datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you don't know beforehand what fields/properties will be persisted then you can use the Datastore API to create and persist [entities](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity.html) on the fly.

```
Entity entity = new Entity("User"); // specify the entity kind
entity.setProperty("name", "someuser"); // add some properties
entity.setProperty("email", "some@user.com");
DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().put(entity); //save it
```

However if you actually want to create 'class' dynamically then this answer would not help.

Comment: this is not what i was looking for , but this solves my problem . thanks :D